# React Native-Routing Issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to react native i tried the [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_router.htm) code to do routing and got struck with error

[image]

Comment: please give a suggestion..............

Answer (score 0):

Oh this looks familiar:

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/494

I hope that it helps.